# Magento Frontend not working without index.php

Tags: magento2, nginx, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

I installed magento 2.4.3-p1. Everything goes good , backend working frontend is working fine but there is an issue. I am able to access the frontend from abc.com/index.php and inner links are working fine like abc.com/dress . But if I try to access my domain with abc.com/ it shows me the nginx error image attached.
Could you please guide where or what I am missing. It seems like something is wrong with the nginx files but I created the default magento nginx config file for server configuration.
[image]

There is not any configuration changed using all default configurations.
**My main purpose is my site home page should work from abc.com instead of abc.com/index.php**

Comment: Have you set up many storefronts in your Magento? If so, you need to set up mapping for the same in the NGINX configuration.

Comment: No I have only 1 storefront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this there was some mistake in nginx.conf file the root was like this.
`root $MAGE_ROOT;`
I changed it to
`root $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;`
Restart nginx
It now started working